# CSS How to make a child bigger when a different child gets smaller

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got some cards that should show a trailer of a website taking the title and a excerpt from that given website. The bottom grey background is a parent div with `display: flex` on it. I've set the container to `height: 200px` and the child elements should fit inside.

Because the title and text can vary from site to site i would like to make them fit as best as possible with just one CSS class.

So, when a title is shorter and only takes up one line, I would like to add one line to the excerpt field.

Is there any way to make that happen with CSS? can `display: flex` handle this? I've tried to use `flex-grow` but it doesn't work

[image: Preview of the example]

Comment: Please post your code, an image is not enough!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71969934/17684809) answer your question ?

Comment: just a suggestion, you can wrap your title and text in another div, make it `display: flex;` as well, `flex-direction: column;` and `justify-content: space-between;` you may need to play with height or overflow property of this div as well. If you would've provided your code sample, it would be much easier and sensible to help you out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.