# Place single child at bottom of flex container flex-direction colum?

Tags: css

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I have two child, I want the first to be at center of page and only the second to be at bottom without using position absolute or affecting first child positioning

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71969934/17684809) may answer your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609

Comment: first of all, I couldn't reproduce your code